# how to get bootstrap datetimepicker in my code

Tags: jquery

```
    //Date picker This is working fine. Able to select the date
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            endDate:new Date()
    })
 //Date Time picker This is not working. Unable to select the date and time
        $('.dateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            endDate: new Date()
        })

I am using
```

```
datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
    and
    <!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
    <script src="../../bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Am I corect if use datetimepicker() function ( AdminLte2 theme)
I have searched on google, no solution found on any of the page.

Comment: Could you post full the page? It means that I think you should add more some the library, my friend.

Comment: view-source:https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/forms/advanced.html

Comment: No, it means that show all html in your code, not template :))

Comment: Added code segment in the below comments

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution:

By adding singleDatePicker: true, we can achieve both date and time

```
    $(".dateTimePicker").daterangepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:ii P',
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: false,
        timePicker: true,
        singleDatePicker: true, //<==HERE
    });
```